# How to read a json object in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My controller has a method that is returning string representation of a jsonArray as

jsonArray.toString()

Now following is the ajax method

```
function loadPropertyFile(url) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url, 
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        alert(obj);
    }
});
```

}

Here the variable obj after parsing comes out to be

```
"[{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemName":"Item Name"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemType":"Type"}]"
```

Now I want to access the values from the keys in js

ie. I want to access the value of key "displaytag.tracking.id"

Problem is when I am doing **console.log(obj[0]["portal.home"]);** It is giving me error **TypeError: obj[0] is undefined**

What shall I do ?

Comment: Is it a string, or do you have an actual javascript object. And this should be trivial to figure out either way ?

Comment: Trivial question, and not clearly formed.

Comment: Question edited. Please see

Comment: Your json string should be like this `'`[{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemName":"Item Name"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemType":"Type"}]`'` remove the double quotes at front and at end use single quotes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to parse the **JSON string** into JavaScript object, and then access the required property:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj[0]["portal.home"]);
```

In older browsers which do not have native JSON support, you should use something like Crockford's [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), which will give you one; please don't use eval() on JSON, as it can lead to pretty bad things all around.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) (or JSON.parse in modern browsers) to convert your string into a Javascript object:

```
var json = '[{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemName":"Item Name"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemType":"Type"}]';
var object = $.parseJSON(json);
```

In your case your JSON string will create an array, so you will need to get the object at the correct index:

```
var portalHomeValue = object[0]["portal.home"];
```

Comment: For old browsers you can use [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). If you don't use jQuery.

Comment: This json object is coming after parsing  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

Comment: @bhuvan if its an object then use `obj[0]['portal.home']`

Comment: @bhuvan If I paste the following into the console I don't get an error and "Home" is returned: `var json = '[{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemName":"Item Name"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemType":"Type"}]'; var object = $.parseJSON(json); console.log(object[0]["portal.home"])`

Comment: nope.. The actual response coming from controller is "{"jsonData":"[{\"portal.home\":\"Home\"},{\"displaytag.tracking.id\":\"Item ID\"},{\"displaytag.tracking.itemName\":\"Item Name\"},{\"displaytag.tracking.itemType\":\"Type\"}]","jsonDataMake":null,"jsonDataModel":null,"jsonDataSoftwareVersion":null,"jsonItemProperties":null,"jsonPositionMethods":null}". After var object = $.parseJSON(json); the response becomes '[{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemName":"Item Name"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemType":"Type"}]'

Answer (score 0):

In case you have the JSON directly in your javascript source (which I don't assume, but I'm adding this for others), you can just remove the quotes, and javascript creates an object based on it:

```
var obj = [{"portal.home":"Home"},{"displaytag.tracking.id":"Item ID"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemName":"Item Name"},{"displaytag.tracking.itemType":"Type"}];
console.log(obj[0]["portal.home"]);
```

Comment: well, following your logic, it is better to use `console.log("Home")` as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access by following

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"Item_Number":"M71118LHB","Description":"MENS ONESIE"}]');
var desc = data[0].Description;
console.log(desc);
```