# PHP 5.5 to SQL Server via PDO, how to pass row contents back to JavaScript jQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, sql-server

I am working on a project that uses jQuery Ajax on the Front-End and PHP 5.5.15 and SQL Server 2014 on the back-end. I have installed drivers for PHP 5.5 to talk to SQL Server from http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html, as Microsoft has failed to provide drivers for this for PHP 5.5 and 5.6 so far (it's been over a year and people are complaining, but, back to the point).

Here is my Ajax call to execute PHP-code server side:

```
$.ajax({type: 'post', 
                async: false,
                url: 'pairrequestsfromdb.php',                  
                data: {
                    toemail: toEmail
                    }, 
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    }
                    }
                );
```

This works fine from this perspective. Now, the PHP code connects to the SQL Server database and queries it for some information. In the case that the result of the PHP SQL Query contains exactly one row, I would like to return the contents of that row to JavaScript in whatever form possible so I can use it there. Here is the php code:

```
$serverName = "WIN-LV4K7BSUPJO";

try

{


  $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=myDB", "myUser", "myPass");

  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  $setDB = $conn->prepare("USE [myDB]");

  $setDB->Execute();


  $tsql = "SELECT [col1],[col2],[col3] FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE col3 = ?";
  $params = array($myParam);
  $checkPairRequests = $conn->prepare($tsql);
  $checkPairRequests->execute($params);
  $pairrequests = $checkPairRequests->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $requestCount = count($pairrequests);

  if ($requestCount > 1)
  {
     die("BAD BAD BAD");
  }
  else if ($requestCount == 0)
  {
     echo "no requests, sign up as pre-request";
  }
  else if ($requestCount == 1)
  {
     // there is exactly one request in the database, all is ok, give ajax the entire row back

    echo $pairrequests;

  }
```

Basically, I use `prepare`, `execute` and `fetchAll`, in that order, to get a result. Now, my question is, how can I return this result, which seems to be stoed in an array, to JavaScript, in some usable form, such as Key-Value String pairs, or even just value string pairs?

At first I tried simply to

```
echo $pairrequests;
```

where `$pairrequests` is the result of the FetchAll Query. However, when I do that, I don't get the actual contents, i get this:

[image]

My next approach was to see if maybe the individual items in the array are strings, so I did this:

```
$row = "";
foreach ($pairrequests as $column)
{     
    $row = $row . $column;
}
echo $row;
```

However, this gives a similar error. So, does anyone have any insight on how I can get and pass the contents of the result row, be it in string form or whatever, back to JavaScript?

Thanks for any and all help,

best regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode your record.

```
echo json_encode($pairrequests);
```

In JS, set the `dataType` of your `$.ajax()` call as `"json"` and the parameter of your `success` callback will be a Javascript object containing the data from your record:

```
success: function (records) {
             alert(records[0].col1 + records[0].col2 + [...]);
         }
```

Comment: beautiful, works like a charm. Thanks! I'd also be interested in what you would recommend to iterate over records, if there are more than one, once in javascript. Some for loop checking for records[i] != NULL, or something like that?

Comment: Use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to easily iterate on the array

Comment: I am still having issues actually acessing members of this returned result. If I alert(result), i get a string that looks like this: "[{"pairID":"6D595AD1-8017-4538-8BDA-8312265E1BD6","name":"username","primaryUniqueUserName":"some(at)gmail.com","secondaryUserEmail":"some.else@gmail.com"}]" Nevermind about the content of this result in particular, what I want is to get the value "username", which is in the "name" column, however both result[0].name and result.name give undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519041/how-to-read-a-json-object-in-js brought the solution, had to parse the object using JSON.parse